# Can we link storage gateway in one account to s3 bucket in another account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-storage-gateway

Is it possible to link storage gateway (s3 file) in aws which is on one account to link it to the s3 bucket present in another account ? Please share some insights.

I have tried finding it but no success, also there is no option to do it from console.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to your question is here.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/filegateway/latest/files3/add-file-share.html#cross-account-access

Another solution would be replicate buckts and mount storagateway in the replicated bucket.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication-walkthrough-2.html